# What conventions are there for business cards to note additional languages spoken?

Tags: professionalism, communication, business-cards

I speak a second language and would like to convey this on my business cards.

What conventions are there for noting additional languages spoken on business cards?

Comment: You're free to put whatever you'd like on your business cards. There are no rules.

Comment: Print a spanish version on the back side of the card?

Comment: Yes, something to the effect of "se habla español" is common, as is a Spanish-only reverse, or single-sided version where everything in English is repeated in Spanish. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be about academia, and is otherwise off-topic here if it is not clear how this situation is specific this particular environment.

Comment: Who do you work for? Your employer may have very specific guidelines for your business cards and if your employer is large enough, they may already have an existing template for dealing with this very specific issue. Also, check your online directory listing, you may want to put something about that in there as well.

Comment: I would say it all depends on what that business card is for. If you're an engineering professor in Maine, nobody will care whether or not you speak Spanish. But if you run a dry-cleaning business in Phoenix, AZ, then that's a different matter.

Comment: This is likely to be closed for being opinion-based, but I think a simple footnote of "I also speak Spanish" or "Services available in Spanish", written *in Spanish*, should do the job.

Comment: I hope the edit keeps in line with the spirit of the question.  Please feel free to roll back if you feel the edit strays from your intention.

Comment: Professional translators often wear flag lapel-pins to indicate languages they are fluent in. That would require color printing, and I'm not sure folks would understand the intent.

Answer (score 2):

If you're bilingual, it's typical to have your business card with each language on either side. If the reverse side of your business card already contains information, then have your business card printed in the primary language of the country/region you'll be distributing them, and indicate on your card that you are also fluent in another language.

Answer (score 1):

People put certifications and also sorts of stuff on a business card
I don't see why not
I would but it where certification are listed which is typically below you name

Answer (score 0):

I've seen "I speak _____ " in small letters written in the language which they speak, for each non-english language.

You could also do the same for each language where the other languages are the primary language on the card but the "Fluent English speaker" is the one(s) in small print.